# XSLT to create multiple element blocks based on comma-separated string

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

**EDIT:** I've got a solution, but I'm sure there are better ways. Please see below.

**Source XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<reservations>
  <reservation>
    <id>1</id>
    <guestId>1111</guestId>
    <!-- other fields -->
  </reservation>
  <reservation>
    <id>2</id>
    <guestId>2222,3333,4444</guestId>
    <!-- other fields -->
  </reservation>
</reservations>
```

**Expected Output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<reservations>
  <reservation>
    <id>1</id>
    <csvGuestString>1111</csvGuestString>
    <guestId>1111</guestId>
    <!-- other fields -->
  </reservation>
  <reservation>
    <id>2</id>
    <csvGuestString>2222,3333,4444</csvGuestString>
    <guestId>2222</guestId>
    <!-- other fields -->
  </reservation>
  <reservation>
    <id>2</id>
    <csvGuestString>2222,3333,4444</csvGuestString>
    <guestId>3333</guestId>
    <!-- other fields -->
  </reservation>
  <reservation>
    <id>2</id>
    <csvGuestString>2222,3333,4444</csvGuestString>
    <guestId>4444</guestId>
    <!-- other fields -->
  </reservation>
</reservations>
```

**Rules:**

1. For `<reservation>` elements that have `n` guests (as defined by comma-separated values in `<guestId>`), replicate that `<reservation>` element -- along with its descendants -- `n` times, each time using the next guestId value.
2. The original `<guestId>` element's value must be retained and must be placed in a new `<csvGuestString>` element.
3. Must be done in XSLT 1.0.
4. Perfectly reasonable to use EXSLT for tokenization.

**What I Have So Far (it works, but no clue if it's the most efficient solution):**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common" 
  exclude-result-prefixes="exsl"
  version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:variable name="vTokenName" select="'token'"/>
  <xsl:variable name="vDoc" select="/"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="guestId">
    <csvGuestString>
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </csvGuestString>   
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="reservation">
    <xsl:variable name="vGuestRtfPass1">
      <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="guestId"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="delimiter" select="','"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:apply-templates select="exsl:node-set($vGuestRtfPass1)/*" mode="pass2">
      <xsl:with-param name="pPosition" select="position()"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="token" mode="pass2">
    <xsl:param name="pPosition" />

    <reservation>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$vDoc/*/reservation[$pPosition]/*" />
        <guestId>
          <xsl:apply-templates />   
        </guestId>
    </reservation>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="tokenize">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:param name="delimiter" select="' '"/>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="contains($text,$delimiter)">
        <xsl:element name="{$vTokenName}">
          <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text,$delimiter)"/>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
          <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text,$delimiter)"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="delimiter" select="$delimiter"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="$text">
        <xsl:element name="{$vTokenName}">
          <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

As always, thank you for your assistance.

Comment: @ColinD - I am currently working on a solution that uses a named tokenizing template to split the CSV string apart, runs the Identity Template on those fragments, but in such a way that each of the original `<reservation>` elements are replicated. My intention was to ask the question here and see if someone can come up with an answer before I do. Should I get there first, I will post; I would relish the opportunity to see if my solution can be made more efficient.

Comment: @ColinD - I have added what I've come up with so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**It isn't necessary to use any `tokenize()` extension function**, and this transformation can be run on an XSLT processor that just has the `xxx:node-set()` extension function:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common" exclude-result-prefixes="ext">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="@*|node()" name="identity">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="reservation/guestId">
   <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
  <csvGuestString><xsl:value-of select="."/></csvGuestString>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="reservation[contains(guestId, ',')]" name="explode">
   <xsl:param name="pCurrent" select="."/>
   <xsl:param name="pLastId" select="substring-before($pCurrent/guestId, ',')"/>

   <xsl:variable name="vrtfResult">
     <xsl:apply-templates select="$pCurrent" mode="explode"/>
   </xsl:variable>
   <xsl:copy-of select="$vrtfResult"/>

   <xsl:variable name="vResult" select="ext:node-set($vrtfResult)/*"/>

   <xsl:if test="contains(substring-after($vResult/csvGuestString, $vResult/guestId), ',')">
     <xsl:call-template name="explode">
       <xsl:with-param name="pCurrent" select="$vResult"/>
       <xsl:with-param name="pLastId" select="$vResult/guestId"/>
     </xsl:call-template>
   </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="node()" mode="explode">
  <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="reservation" mode="explode">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" mode="explode"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="guestId[contains(.,',')]" mode="explode">
  <csvGuestString><xsl:value-of select="."/></csvGuestString>
  <guestId><xsl:value-of select="substring-before(., ',')"/></guestId>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="guestId" mode="explode">
  <guestId>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(concat(../csvGuestString, ','), concat(current(),',')), ',')"/>
  </guestId>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<reservations>
  <reservation>
    <id>1</id>
    <guestId>1111</guestId>
    <!-- other fields -->
  </reservation>
  <reservation>
    <id>2</id>
    <guestId>2222,3333,4444</guestId>
    <!-- other fields -->
  </reservation>
</reservations>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<reservations>
  <reservation>
    <id>1</id>
    <guestId>1111</guestId>
    <csvGuestString>1111</csvGuestString>
    <!-- other fields -->
  </reservation>
  <reservation>
    <id>2</id>
    <csvGuestString>2222,3333,4444</csvGuestString>
    <guestId>2222</guestId>
    <!-- other fields -->
  </reservation>
  <reservation>
    <id>2</id>
    <csvGuestString>2222,3333,4444</csvGuestString>
    <guestId>3333</guestId>
    <!-- other fields -->
  </reservation>
  <reservation>
    <id>2</id>
    <csvGuestString>2222,3333,4444</csvGuestString>
    <guestId>4444</guestId>
    <!-- other fields -->
  </reservation>
</reservations>
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the `tokenize` method of the EXSLT string functions:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings"
  exclude-result-prefixes="str">

<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="reservation">
  <xsl:variable name="this" select="."/>
  <xsl:for-each select="str:tokenize(guestId, ',')" >
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$this" mode="copy">
      <xsl:with-param name="id" select="."/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="reservation" mode="copy">
  <xsl:param name="id"/>
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()">
      <xsl:with-param name="id" select="$id"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="reservation/guestId">
  <xsl:param name="id"/>
  <csvGuestString>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </csvGuestString>
  <guestId>
    <xsl:value-of select="$id"/>
  </guestId>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

That way xsltproc transforms your input sample into

```
<reservations>
  <reservation>
    <id>1</id>
    <csvGuestString>1111</csvGuestString>
    <guestId>1111</guestId>
    <!-- other fields -->
  </reservation>
  <reservation>
    <id>2</id>
    <csvGuestString>2222,3333,4444</csvGuestString>
    <guestId>2222</guestId>
    <!-- other fields -->
  </reservation>
  <reservation>
    <id>2</id>
    <csvGuestString>2222,3333,4444</csvGuestString>
    <guestId>3333</guestId>
    <!-- other fields -->
  </reservation>
  <reservation>
    <id>2</id>
    <csvGuestString>2222,3333,4444</csvGuestString>
    <guestId>4444</guestId>
    <!-- other fields -->
  </reservation>
</reservations>
```

Comment: Makes sense: if you're already using EXSLT, why not take advantage of `tokenize`? Thank you for your help, @Martin.